# Find the closest table containing a text

Tags: jquery

I've 3 nested tables with innermost table containing some text in the **td** portion.

What is the way to get the innermost table containing this text?

If I run something like:

```
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text().match(/PNR No:/);}).closest('table')
```

it gives me 3 tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It gives me 3 tables

It's returning 3 tables because each `td` element presumably contains that text (since they are nested).

> What is the way to get the innermost table containing this text?

If you want to select the innermost `td` element, one solution would be to select the `td` elements that don't contain table elements (i.e., the innermost `td` elements) by combining the [`:not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and the [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
$("td:not(:has(table))").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().match(/PNR No:/);
}).closest('table');
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jsgr542v)